# How can I get this API call to only return when Student_ID = the ID I am providing

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-web-api

I am using ASP.NET Core to run my API through my Microsoft Management Studio SQL server.

How can I get this get request to only return data of Student_ID that I provide. As seen below that is the object I get when I call this GET: api/Grades but I only want it to display when my Student_ID match my ID.

```
    public IQueryable<Grade> GetGrades()
    {
        return db.Grades;
    }

    // GET: api/Grades/5
    [ResponseType(typeof(Grade))]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetGrade(int id)
    {
        Grade grade = await db.Grades.FindAsync(id);
        if (grade == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok(grade);
    }
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please do **not** post code as images. See here for more details why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551

Comment: I am new with stack overflow sorry is it correct now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, according to the [FindAsync documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.findasync?view=efcore-3.1), it returns the entity which has the specified primary key.

> Finds an entity with the given primary key values.

I'm **assuming** that your call above is probably returning the grade which has "Grade_ID=5".

Your second problem is likely to be that there may be multiple rows which have grades for a student, but it looks like you are attempting to return only 1 `Grade` entity.

The code which you probably want to execute would be something like this:

```
IEnumerable<Grade> grades = await db.Grades.Where((g) => g.Student_ID == id)
                                           .ToListAsync();
if (!grades.Any())
{
    return this.NotFound();
}

return this.Ok(grades);
```

`.Where` is [Linq](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/) that is [converted into a SQL query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/linq-to-entities) to return the data.
It is worth familiarising yourself with Linq in general because it's incredibly useful for working with data.

Comment: ExceptionMessage: "Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Object'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.

Comment: I have changed the `.Equals` to be `==` in the query above. See if that helps.